# Simple Spring boot filter not working properly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I am trying to access an endpoint of a spring boot application with some filters applied on it but the filters are not working properly.I need some help regarding this problem I am providing the suspective things below.

```
package com.ronit.Restfulwebservice.filtering;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonValue;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.FilterProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleBeanPropertyFilter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleFilterProvider;

@RestController
public class FilteringController {
    @GetMapping("/filtering")
    public MappingJacksonValue filtering() {
        
        SomeBean someBean = new SomeBean("value1", "value2", "value3");
        
        MappingJacksonValue mappingJacksonValue = new MappingJacksonValue(someBean);
        
        SimpleBeanPropertyFilter filter = 
                SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("field1","field3");
        
        FilterProvider filters = 
                new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("SomeBeanFilter", filter);
        
        mappingJacksonValue.setFilters(filters);
        
        return mappingJacksonValue;
    }

    @GetMapping("/filtering-list")
    public MappingJacksonValue filteringList() {
        
        List<SomeBean> list = Arrays.asList(new SomeBean("value1", "value2", "value3"),
                new SomeBean("value4", "value5", "value6"));
        
        MappingJacksonValue mappingJacksonValue = new MappingJacksonValue(list);
        
        SimpleBeanPropertyFilter filter = 
                SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept("field2");
        
        FilterProvider filters = 
                new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("SomeBeanFilter", filter);
        
        mappingJacksonValue.setFilters(filters);
        
        return mappingJacksonValue;
    }
}
```

This is the SomeBean class

```
package com.ronit.Restfulwebservice.filtering;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFilter;
//@JsonIgnoreProperties({"field1"})
public class SomeBean {
    private String field1;
    //@JsonIgnore
    @JsonFilter("SomeBeanFilter")
    //@JsonFilter("ListFilter")
    private String field2;
    private String field3;

    public SomeBean(String field1, String field2, String field3) {
        super();
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
        this.field3 = field3;
    }

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }

    public String getField3() {
        return field3;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SomeBean [field1=" + field1 + ", field2=" + field2 + ", field3=" + field3 + "]";
    }
}
```

This is the Application class

```
package com.ronit.Restfulwebservice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RestfulWebServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestfulWebServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The application.properties file

```
logging.level.org.springframework=debug
```

The pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ronit</groupId>
    <artifactId>Restful-web-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Restful-web-service</name>
    <description>My first rest api </description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>20</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            </dependency>-->
            <!-- This dependency below converts json file to xml format without this dependency
             xml instead of json is given to the browser and the browser displays the same -->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Json response for http://localhost:8080/filtering-list endpoint

```
[
{
"field1": "value1",
"field2": "value2",
"field3": "value3"
},
{
"field1": "value4",
"field2": "value5",
"field3": "value6"
}
]
```

Json response for http://localhost:8080/filtering endpoint

```
{
"field1": "value1",
"field2": "value2",
"field3": "value3"
}
```

I am following a course on udemy I made the exact same thing in the tutorial and followed the step by step guide on github and built the exact same thing but it is not working . I have searched online for solutions but I found none please help me with this problem . If more details on anything is required please ask thanks in advance

Comment: I am unable to understand where I made the mistake if I get help asap it will save my day please consider helping .Have a good day thanks in advance if anyone helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the provided code, it seems like you are using MappingJacksonValue and SimpleBeanPropertyFilter from Jackson to apply dynamic filtering to the JSON response. The code looks correct, and the response for the endpoint ***/filtering-list*** looks fine. However, the issue might be related to the configuration or usage of the filter.

Below, I suggest some points to check:

**1.** Verify if the ObjectMapper bean is correctly configured in the application. Make sure to register the FilterProvider with the ObjectMapper bean so that it recognizes the filter.

**2.** Ensure that the SomeBean class is annotated with @JsonFilter("SomeBeanFilter"), which you already have correctly.

**3.** Check for any other filter or interceptor configurations that may be affecting the JSON response.

**4.** Make sure you are accessing the correct URL for the endpoint ***/filtering***.

An example to configure the bean:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.FilterProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleFilterProvider;

@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("SomeBeanFilter",
                SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("field2"));
        objectMapper.setFilterProvider(filters);
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

If you have tried the above steps and the issue persists, I recommend checking for other custom configurations, filters, or interceptors that might be interfering with the filtering process. Additionally, review if there are any error logs or exceptions when accessing the ***/filtering*** endpoint.

Comment: I have checked everything as you said but I could not find any problem still it persists . When I try to use the ObjectMapper instead I got an empty json response

Comment: I found some error in the class someBean . I had accidentally put the "someBeanFilter" on field2 a String instead of the class I placed it on the class and everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

I found out my mistake I had put the @JsonFilter("someBeanFilter") annotation on the String property field2 instead of the class . I put it on the class and now everything works fine .